# Why is my WMI query for CIM_LogicalDisk events returning Win32_LogicalDisk events but not Win32_MappedLogicalDisk events?

Tags: .net, wmi, wmi-query, network-drive

I have a [**System.Management.WqlEventQuery**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.wqleventquery.aspx) listening for the `"__InstanceOperationEvent"` event.  This event is the base class for the `"__InstanceCreationEvent"`, `"__InstanceDeletionEvent"`, and `"__InstanceModificationEvent"` events, so it captures all three.

When my **WqlEventQuery.Condition** is `"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk'"`, I get events for logical disks only, as expected.

However, when my **WqlEventQuery.Condition** is `"(TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' or TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_MappedLogicalDisk')"`, I still get only **Win32_LogicalDisk** events.
Alternatively, I should also be able to use **WqlEventQuery.Condition** set as `"TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_LogicalDisk'"`, because **CIM_LogicalDisk** is the base class for both **Win32_LogicalDisk** and **Win32_MappedLogicalDisk**. Unfortunately, this alternative query also returns only **Win32_LogicalDisk** events.

In summary, I cannot seem to capture **Win32_MappedLogicalDisk** events.  My assumption is that such an event should be generated when I right click a network share and map it as a network drive to a new drive letter.  Despite this new mapped drive showing up in Explorer just fine, my program never receives any event.

Are any of my assumptions wrong?  What is a [**Win32_MappedLogicalDrive**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394194%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or what distinguishes it from a [**Win32_LogicalDrive**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) whose **DriveType** is "NetworkDrive"?  How can I capture events for connecting/disconnecting network drives using WMI?

**UPDATE:** I posted more on this problem here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsmanagement/thread/1c92f08b-b9c9-4f27-a1bb-0c16a8868d19  It's turning out to be an unfortunate side-effect of UAC, with no work around except to create duplicate drive mappings under an administrative account.

Answer (score 3):

I searched around figuring this was (as usual) some kind of Vista/Window 7 UAC-related behavior, and sure-enough... http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/270814-win32_mappedlogicaldisk-returns-null-vista.html

Since mapped drives are "per user", a drive mapped by a non-elevated user (e.g. from Explorer) cannot be seen by a WMI query running elevated as administrator.  That's counter-intuitive, because usually an application can access more information running as an administrator, not less.  So depending on who mapped the drive, it may be visible to a program depending on whether it's running with elevated privileges or not.  I guess I will have to use the impersonation options to ensure the program locates all the drives it can possibly access.

In addition, once this was working, I saw duplicate entries for networked drives and realized that the set of Win32_LogicalDisk objects includes Win32_MappedLogicalDisk objects, even though Win32_MappedLogicalDIsk is not a Win32_LogicalDisk as far as any class hierarchy is concerned.  Win32_MappedLogicalDisk, like Win32_LogicalDisk, extends directly from CIM_LogicalDisk according to the documentation.

See discussion on problems caused by UAC for mapped drives here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx?PageIndex=2

Excerpt:

> "My stub is running elevated to admin.
>   Are you suggesting that somehow it can
>   detect what drives the standard user
>   had mapped, and then do the mapping
>   again? Or do I need two stubs: the
>   first runs **without** elevation, a
>   makes a list (say, to the registry) of
>   the mapped drives, then shells out to
>   stub #2, which asks for elevation to
>   admin, reads the registry list and
>   re-maps the drives.   **Sounds kinda
>   Rube Goldberg-like to me!**"

Another workaround is kind of like duplicating the drive mappings for administrators, but involves allowing normal user drive mappings to be shared with administrators by linking thier tokens.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624